# Remove case sensitive duplicates from lookup ax 2012

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, x++

I have a lookup in which I am inserting values on run time, all things are going fine. Requirement is to avoid replicating values if case sensitive. Like ABCD and abcd should not be there in lookup at a time.

Below is my code that I've tried so far.

```
public void lookup()
{

   Query query = new Query();
    QueryBuildDataSource queryBuildDataSource;
    QueryBuildRange queryBuildRange;
    SysTableLookup sysTableLookup = SysTableLookup::newParameters(tableNum(InventJournalTrans), this);

    sysTableLookup.addLookupField(fieldNum(InventJournalTrans,vehicleNo));


    queryBuildDataSource = query.addDataSource(tableNum(InventJournalTrans));
    queryBuildDataSource.addSortField(fieldNum(InventJournalTrans,vehicleNo),SortOrder::Descending);
    queryBuildDataSource.addRange(fieldNum(InventJournalTrans, vehicleNo)).value(SysQuery::valueNotEmptyString());

    sysTableLookup.parmQuery(query);
    QueryBuildDataSource.orderMode(OrderMode::GroupBy);
    sysTableLookup.performFormLookup();



    this.replaceOnLookup();
}
```

Here is the image of lookup.

[image]

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

I can't reproduce the issue, for me your code works fine. But try to add this line of code, I hope this will help

```
sysTableLookup.parmUseLookupValue(false);
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your database, table or field must use a case sensitive collating sequence.

You will have to fix that.

In older version you could use Oracle as a backend database where this could be an issue. The only workaround was to normalise the data using `strUpr` or `strLwr` before saving data.